# Loading Bitmaps and display in ImageView Efficiently

Tags: android, bitmap, uiimageview

My program is to decode a bitmap and display it.

The origin decode code and display code works perfect on my pc.

When I use the code in my android device, the code also can decode the stream.

The problem is the image show in the ImageView is't efficiently.

below is part of my code

I use a thread to call the decode function and than show it on ImageView

```
class ProcessData extends Thread{
    Message message;
        String obj="run";
        ReadRawFileImage readMyRawData=new ReadRawFileImage();


    public void run() { 

           Log.e("///enter ProcessData thread ","ProcessData thread");   
        while(true){
        Bitmap image=Bitmap.createBitmap (320, 240, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                    image.setPixels(pixelData,0,320 ,0 ,0,320,240);
        message = handler.obtainMessage(1,obj);
        handler.sendMessage(message);
            }  

public Handler handler = new Handler(){ 


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);           
            String MsgString = (String)msg.obj;

            if (MsgString.equals("run"))
            {             Log.e("///enter handler ","setImageBitmap");                                                                                                   
                          myImageView.setImageBitmap(image);

            }


    }
};
```

***Logcat***

```
   05-21 20:11:44.845: E/1(7267): 1
   05-21 20:11:44.845: E/ProcessData thread(7267): ProcessData thread
   05-21 20:11:44.845: E////enter handler(7267): setImageBitmap
   05-21 20:11:44.855: D/dalvikvm(7267): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 22% free 10613K/13575K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 34ms
   05-21 20:11:44.855: D/dalvikvm(7267): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 8ms
   05-21 20:11:44.915: D/dalvikvm(7267): GC_CONCURRENT freed 895K, 25% free 10225K/13575K, paused 13ms+6ms, total 39ms
   05-21 20:11:44.980: D/dalvikvm(7267): GC_CONCURRENT freed 439K, 25% free 10298K/13575K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 35ms
   05-21 20:11:44.980: D/dalvikvm(7267): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 22ms
   05-21 20:11:45.030: D/dalvikvm(7267): GC_CONCURRENT freed 473K, 24% free 10337K/13575K, paused 1ms+4ms, total 26ms
   05-21 20:11:45.030: D/dalvikvm(7267): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
   05-21 20:11:45.095: D/dalvikvm(7267): GC_CONCURRENT freed 467K, 24% free 10382K/13575K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 46ms
   05-21 20:11:45.100: D/dalvikvm(7267): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 41ms
   05-21 20:11:45.185: D/dalvikvm(7267): GC_CONCURRENT freed 450K, 24% free 10443K/13575K, paused 12ms+5ms, total 55ms
   05-21 20:11:45.185: D/dalvikvm(7267): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 29ms
   05-21 20:11:45.255: D/dalvikvm(7267): GC_CONCURRENT freed 469K, 23% free 10486K/13575K, paused 12ms+5ms, total 48ms
   05-21 20:11:45.255: D/dalvikvm(7267): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 27ms
   05-21 20:11:45.320: D/dalvikvm(7267): GC_CONCURRENT freed 455K, 23% free 10542K/13575K, paused 12ms+5ms, total 48ms
   05-21 20:11:45.320: D/dalvikvm(7267): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 22ms
   05-21 20:11:45.395: D/dalvikvm(7267): GC_CONCURRENT freed 448K, 22% free 10605K/13575K, paused 11ms+5ms, total 50ms
   05-21 20:11:45.395: D/dalvikvm(7267): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 25ms
```

.....................

and then set my bitmap again!

and then show the kind of 10605K/13575K, paused 11ms+5ms, total 50ms again~~

Comment: What do you mean by "is not efficient", what is exactly your problem?

Comment: the image must change very fast!
because it is from a video camera.

Comment: The image change in my android device need about 3 second to change.

I want to change the image every 1/30 second.

Comment: Why do you have to display images so fast? Are you talking about videos?

Comment: yes!!
my video camera device send the data.

Comment: I think you are not on the right direction, maybe have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageView` is not built for video previews. And you don't create `Bitmap`'s on the fly in real time applications either.

Use `SurfaceView`,`TextureView` or `SurfaceTexture` for rendering camera frames.